# Bash Terminal Command for renaming multiple files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

As the title suggests, I am looking for a bash command (or maybe even a perl command) that I can use in terminal to help me rename files in a folder.

I am a DJ and receive music weekly via a zip file containing hundreds of new music but file name is usually inconsistent and sometimes files have various characters before the title of the song. I am looking to replace any character before the first letter as well as remove the any extra spaces at the end of a string.

```
Original < 01 - Artist - Song .mp3

New > Arist - Song.mp3

Original < _Artist - Song.mp3

New > Artist - Song.mp3

Original < 04 04 )(*)*+ Artist - Song.wav

New < Artist - Song.wav
```

I found a bash with a regex a few months back that handles [0-9] characters in the front of a string and I've tried a few things but nothing really worked so I am posting here to see if someone could help. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

My attempts

```
for f in [0-9]* ; do
   if[[ $f =~ ^[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+(.+) ]] ; then
      newname = "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      echo "> $newname"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Try the `rename` command.

Comment: @Barmar what is the rename command?

Comment: It's a script that uses perl regular expressions to rename files.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below rename command on the directory where the files you want to rename are located.

```
rename 's/^[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z]+) - ([A-Za-z]+)[^.]*/$1 - $2/' *.*
```

OR

```
rename 's/^[^A-Za-z]*|\s+(?=\.[^.]*$)//g' *.*
```

Comment: First one gave me: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `[A-Za-z]+'

Comment: Second gave me: -bash: s/^[^A-Za-z]*|\s+(?=\.[^.]*$)//g: No such file or directory

Comment: @Chris Sounds like you didn't put quotes around the first argument.

Comment: @Chris did you put the quotes?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I didn't but I just did that. I got this: -bash: rename: command not found

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
sed -r 's/(^[^a-zA-Z]*|\s+)//g'
```

renaming every files in a directory

```
for file in *;
do 
new=`echo $file | sed -r 's/(^[^a-zA-Z]*|\s+)//g'`; 
mv "$file" $new; 
done
```

Comment: Files can be various types, ie .mp3, .wav, .flac, .m4a, .aac, .aiff, etc.

Comment: Also, got this: `sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]`

Comment: If the entire files are to renamed in the directory, just `for file in *` would be fine, which would iterate through all the files in the direcotry. I have edited the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily adjust your existing regex to your updated requirements.

```
if [[ $f =~ ^[^A-Za-z]*(.+[^ ]) *(\....)$ ]] ; then
    newname="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

This assumes that there is always a three-character filename extension. You could change the second parenthesized expression to something like `(\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,5})` to restrict it to only alphanumerics, and allow a length between 2 and 5 characters.

Your code could not have worked the way you wrote it, because it had some spacing errors. The space after `if` is significant, and you cannot have spaces on either side of the equals sign in the assignment.

Comment: The if statement gives me: 

`-bash: syntax error in conditional expression`


`-bash: syntax error near `*('`


Also note that file name could be more or less than three as well. EX: `.aiff`, `.flac`, `.rm`, `.ra`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

that last one looks weird unless you meant: strip anything before the first dash or underscore which starts with numbers, may have some text in parentheses, dashes underscores and ends in a dash with (or without) a blank before artist name.

Try this:

    `#!/bin/bash
    for f in [0-9]* ; do
       echo $f
       if [[ $f =~  ^([0-9 ]+|[-_\*]+|\(.+\)|[[:blank:]]*)*(.+) ]]; then
          newname="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
          echo "> ${newname}"
       fi
    done`

Just so we are clear there is a limit of what you can do with a regex in bash. for example all matches are "greedy". So the recommended way is to do this using either sed, awk or perl.

Comment: The last one is showing when the first character is `NOT` an alphabetical character and removing all of the characters until there is an alphabetic character.

Comment: I've never used sed, awk or perl. Which of the three would you recommend and how would I do it in that language?