# How can I rename files with a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have files named like this:

- 2014-8-1.txt
- 2014-08-02.txt
- 2014-9-03.txt
- 2014-09-4.txt

How can I rename those files to the following names? ('-' hyphens will be replaced with '_' underscores.)

- 2014_8_1.txt
- 2014_08_02.txt
- 2014_9_03.txt
- 2014_09_4.txt

Comment: Do you have the `rename` command?

Comment: Sometimes there's a `prename` (Perl-based `rename`) command.  It makes it trivial: `prename s/-/_/g 2014-10-1?.txt` or equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I have. I hadn't known rename command. Looks like it is the perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: See also [Bash terminal command for renaming multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696689/bash-terminal-command-for-renaming-multiple-files).  That was asked minutes ago; there are multiple other questions about renaming files in a shell script too from a years ago.

Comment: Actually the file names are little more complicated. Let me reedit the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mv `ls *-*.txt` `ls *-*.txt | sed 's/-/_/g'`
```

mv - renames file
ls with wildcard - will list all the files with "-" in it
sed - will search for - in filename and replace it with _ any number of occurances.

Comment: Parsing `ls` output must be avoided anytime.

Comment: Space and newlines in files are not really special, all the unix flavors allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `find`:

```
find . -type f -name [0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*.txt -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'f="{}"; echo mv "$f" "${f//-/_}"'
```

Comment: Thanks. This can be used even for more complicated rename. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes and don't forget to remove `echo` and make it `mv` later.